# inside the usercontroler which is dynamically loaded,FileUploadField issue

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net, ashx

my question is related to the fileupload control.I am loading my usercontrollers dynamically via ashx handler.so far so good.but when I put

```
 <ext:FileUploadField runat="server"  />
```

my ashx handler give me error which tell me null reference .

I am doing this with  the text,textfield elements ,in that case, no problem ,my user control loading without no problems.

(`<ext:TextField runat="server" FieldLabel="deneme"></ext:TextField>`)
someone tell me where is the problem .

here is the my ashx handler,

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {


            string mainTabPnl = context.Request["container"];
            string url = context.Request["url"];
            string id = context.Request["id"];





            Ext.Net.Panel pn = new Ext.Net.Panel() 
            {
                Title = "MY TITLE",
                Closable = true,
                Layout = "Fit",
                Height=500,
                ID=id,

                Items = {
                    new UserControlLoader{
                    Path=url
                    }

                }
            };



            pn.AddTo(mainTabPnl);

            new DirectResponse().Return();



        }
```

Comment: Are you using any update Panel? In Such case File upload control will not work...Rest of the fileds like text box will work...

Comment: nope no update panel.

Comment: actually handler turn a bunch of javascript and browser handle those code,in a sense ,like I am using update panel ,as it is ajax request.

Comment: Then it wont work...Try some other control like Rad Asynchronous control (Telerik)...I am not sure about asynchronous file upload control..

Answer (score 0):

```
ext:FileUploadField
```

should be placed inside html form tag

```
<form>
  <ext:FileUploadField
</form>
```